# Emoticons in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Does Codename One support emoticons without problems, both in terms of storage and display, or are there limits?

Can I safely use them in Label, TextArea, store them on files with utf-8 encoding?

Maybe the question is trivial, but I don’t know exactly what kind of encoding they use.

Comment: I don't know for sure. There are a lot of nuances with emoticons and I recall we fixed some of these issues but it's very possible some edge cases remain.They are a serious pain to work with.